# DevExpress DateEdit in standalone mode on form: any way to eliminate highlight of the Month name?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, text-editor

When the user selects a date from the calendar view dropdown, the editor displays something like:
            Monday, `November` 5, 2012

with "November" in `reverse highlight`, as if the text were selected.  Is there a simple way to display plain text without that highlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TextEditStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_TextEditStyletopic) property allows you to control the manner in which text is displayed within the editor and in which text is edited. To display text without any selection and editing you can use the [TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsTextEditStylesEnumtopic) value for this property:

```
this.textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy";
this.textEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
this.textEdit1.Properties.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;
```